# What is the UTI type for notes written in iOS Notes App?

Tags: ios8, uti, ios-extensions

What is the UTI type for Notes written in iOS Notes App. Is it public.plain-text or something else. Though public.plain-text works but it then supports all the text files also. I just want to import Notes from Notes App to my application. I am using Extension for that.